# Creating a Custom Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I'm a graphic designer who has also been tasked with building a website for the church that I work for. I've built many websites in the past, so this isn't an issue at all, however, something that I'm looking to do with this site is to have as many elements that can just simply run on their own as possible. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to JavaScript, and honestly don't really have an idea at all about what I'm doing.

I'd like for the new site to have a custom countdown timer that will count down to when we go live, and then display a link for our live stream for a set period of time, and then reset. The code below shows what I've already managed to write from just searching around on the internet. The problem with it is that it relies on a person (which half of the time is a web-volunteer) to remember to change the date and time to the next service after the current service is finished, and 90% of the time they forget.

In a perfect world, I'd like for this countdown timer to automatically countdown to the nearest Tuesday at 6:00 pm, then show a link to our live stream for 20 minutes, then reset. Or if Sunday at 10:00 am comes first, countdown to Sunday at 10am, then show a link to our live stream for one hour and 15 minutes, and then reset. Theoretically I would imagine this could run indefinitely as it would just check for if Tuesday at 6pm comes first, or if Sunday at 10am comes first, then countdown to those times, pause, show some hyperlinked text, and then repeat.

I apologize if this has already been talked about here, I tried searching as thoroughly as I could and couldn't find anything.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo" class="countdown-live" style="text-align:center;"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("October 20, 2020 18:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " d " + hours + " h "
  + minutes + " m & " + seconds + " s";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="https://newhopechurchtn.org/new-hope-online">Watch Live!</a>';
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A better solution than manually entering a date after each event would be to run a simple HTTP server and use AJAX to get the data you need. That way, you could put in your whole schedule for the next few months and have it automatically update. It would also make it so your website would work regardless of how messed up the system clock is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little delayed but here's something that works with a little maintenance.

```js
(() => {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate = currentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: "America/New_York"
  });

  // Service times    
  var serviceTEN = "2021/12/06 11:15";
  var serviceTWELVE = "2021/12/06 13:45";
  var serviceTWO = "2021/12/06 15:45";
  var serviceFIVE = "2021/12/06 16:45";
  var serviceSEVEN = "2021/12/06 19:45";
  var waiting;

  // Set current service
  var currentService = serviceTEN;


  function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "0" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length - size);
  }

  // Get the current time, set the correct timezone, and parse it to the same layout.
  // Find the difference between the current date and the service time. 
  // Have that be the time remaining.
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var now = new Date();
    now = now.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      timeZone: "America/New_York"
    });

    // Parse the date to find each variable (seconds, minutes, hours, days)

    let t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(now);
    let seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    let hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    let days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    return {
      total: t,
      days: days,
      hours: hours,
      minutes: minutes,
      seconds: seconds,
    };
  }

  // the id refers to "js-clock" which is the beginning of the ID, this can be changed
  function clock(id, endtime) {
    let days = document.getElementById(id + "-days");
    let hours = document.getElementById(id + "-hours");
    let minutes = document.getElementById(id + "-minutes");
    let seconds = document.getElementById(id + "-seconds");

    let timeinterval = setInterval(function() {
      let t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

      // Look through the service times and figure out which service it should be.
      if (t.total <= 0) {
        if (waiting === true) {
          location.reload();
        } else if (t.total < -300000) {
          switch (endtime) {
            case serviceTEN:
              endtime = serviceTWELVE;
              break;
            case serviceTWELVE:
              endtime = serviceTWO;
              break;
            case serviceTWO:
              endtime = serviceFIVE;
              break;
            case serviceFIVE:
              endtime = serviceSEVEN;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        } else {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      } else {
        waiting = true;
        // Edit the 2 or 3 to change amount of digits
        days.innerHTML = pad(t.days, 3);
        hours.innerHTML = pad(t.hours, 2);
        minutes.innerHTML = pad(t.minutes, 2);
        seconds.innerHTML = pad(t.seconds, 2);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  clock("js-clock", currentService);
})();
```

```html
<div class="mainOverlayCountdown-k" id="mainOverlayCountdownID-k">
  <h1 id="countdownHeader-k">Next service begins in:</h1>
  <div class="countdown-cover">
    <div id="js-clock" class="countdowntimer">

      <div id="js-clock-days" class="clock-number">00</div>
      <div class="clock-label">Days</div>

      <div id="js-clock-hours" class="clock-number">00</div>
      <div class="clock-label">Hrs</div>

      <div id="js-clock-minutes" class="clock-number">00</div>
      <div class="clock-label">Min</div>

      <div id="js-clock-seconds" class="clock-number">00</div>
      <div class="clock-label">Sec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To change the service times, edit the service'TIME' Variables. You might have to play around with it to get the correct timezone.

to add/delete service times, but make sure you also add/delete it in the variables where you set the date, and the switch function.

Hope this helps!